# dotnet watch run blazor wasm loading pdb symbols

Tags: .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-client-side

Should I be able to attach the debugger to a blazor wasm project using the visual studio 2019 professional edition?  When I use dotnet watch run, I can't get the symbols to load to hit the breakpoints. It works fine with iisexpress but not when I use dotnet watch run. Any ideas or articles to look at would be appreciated.

Comment: check this : https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/01/01/live-coding-net-core-using-dotnet-watch/

Comment: I have viewed this article and the attached process appears to work. However, my breakpoint symbols display the circle with the red outline and small yellow triangle saying the breakpoint symbols could not be loaded. I was wondering if it is because the application is blazor wasm.